# python matching files from one list with files from another list based on name

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I am learning python and programing in general and really need some assistance.

I wrote a python script that reads one file, get unique values, opens a second file and and uses those unique values to makes some calculation(script is too long to upload)
I then created a gui using pyqt4 where I allowed the user to browse by clicking `QPushButton`  and stored the file path in `QLineEdit` I then set my file in my script as `f1 = self.lineedit.text()` and `f2 = self.lineedit2.text`
everything worked perfectly however, I need to allow to user to select multiple files and match every file one with its corresponding file two since they are dependent on each other

Here are the updates I made to the widget functions to accept multiple files:

```
def first_file_set(self): 
    dlg = QFileDialog()
    files = dlg.getOpenFileNames()
    self.listWidget.addItems(list(files))        

def second_file_set(self):
    dlg = QFileDialog()
    filenames = dlg.getOpenFileNames()
    self.listWidget_2.addItems(list(filenames))


def clearF(self):
    for item in self.listwidget2.selectedItems():
        self.listWidget.clear()

def clearS(self):
    for item in self.listwidget.selectedItems():
        self.listWidget_2.clear() 

def Calculate(self):
 #code is too long this is how I am reading files
   l1 = []
   f1 = self.listWidget.item()

    with open(f1,'r') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for line in csvreader:
            l1.append(list(line)) 
        # more code

    l2 = []
    f2 = self.listWidget_2.item()[0]

    with open(f2,'r') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for line in csvreader:
            l2.append(list(line))   
            # more code
```

I still want to use the code I wrote but on multiple files this time.

eg.

open one file from file path in `listwidget`, grab unique items, find file with same name from its path in `listwidget_2` use unique items to perform calculations, repeat for every file in list

If my file one and two will have the same string in their name how do I pull and match them?

Example file one names:
filemap02.csv
filemap03.csv
filemap04.csv

Example file two names:
newmap02.csv
newmap03.csv
newmap04.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't really test it since you did not post a working example, but something like this should do it:

```
for item in self.listwidget.selectedItems():
    #First file
    fn1=str(item.text())

    #Get string that needs to match
    matchStr=fn1.replace("file","")

    #Find matching item in second listwidget    
    fn2=self.listwidget2.findItems(matchStr,QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)

    # Do your calculations 
    whateverFunc(fn1,fn2)
```

Hope that helps.